# How to operate file in bit

Tags: file, bit

I have a very big file, 1TB for example, I want to move the first bit(not byte) to last, as I know all method that read/write file must be in byte, it's slow to shift all byte in that file. 
**So is there any method to operate a file in bit?**
PS:Any programming language is OK.

Comment: No. You'll have to rewrite every single byte of that file. Better to incorporate that bit-shifting logic in the code that reads the file, rather than actually changing the file itself.

Comment: I do know that, but I wish someone can give me a surprise answer